# Flutter: Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am using VScode to code with Flutter, How can i solve this problem? before updating  it was working perfect but now this problem! even typping flutter doctor giving this issue!
please help!

Here is the full error:

```
$ flutter doctor
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ee76268252c22f5c11e82a7b87423ca3982e51a7...
Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK.
```

Comment: Post the error in full please. also `flutter doctor`

Comment: $ flutter doctor
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ee76268252c22f5c11e82a7b87423ca3982e51a7...
Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue. Don't pacnic. Open Windows `cmd` or Ubuntu/MacOS/Linux `terminal` and run `flutter upgrade -v` .

It takes time to download and sometimes if failed error doesn't appear in IDE.
In terminal/cmd you can see the progress.

Restart your IDE once the upgrade finishes.

Comment: it didnt solve the problem , anyway same issue: $ flutter upgrade -v
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ee76268252c22f5c11e82a7b87423ca3982e51a7...
Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK.

Comment: You executed in `terminal` ? Which OS you are using?

Comment: yes i used VScode terminal, i am using windows 8,1 ...  I dont know how to solve this problem, i just updted from notification , and now this problem!(

Comment: no no, you need to use windows terminal, Windows Command prompt

Comment: @FeliksBekeshov any progress?

Comment: nooo, no any progress, cmd is not even responding,(((   , in git bush it is written like: "Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ee76268252c22f5c11e82a7b87423ca3982e51a7...
Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK." same problem

Comment: Run `git bash` or `cmd` as administrator and then execute

Comment: For VS code users: Just close and open your IDE, it will start downloading the Dart SDK.

Answer (score 1):

i slove that error reinstall the Dart SDK using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install).

> Important: These commands require administrator rights. Here’s one way to open a Command Prompt window that has admin rights:

Press Windows+R to open the Run window.
Type cmd into the box.

> Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

To install the Dart SDK:

> `choco install dart-sdk`

To upgrade the Dart SDK:

> `choco upgrade dart-sdk`

By default, the SDK is installed at C:\tools\dart-sdk. You can change that location by setting the ChocolateyToolsLocation environment variable to your chosen installation directory.

If you can’t use the Dart SDK executables, add the SDK location to your PATH:

1. In the Windows search box, type env.
2. Click Edit the system environment variables.
3. Click Environment Variables….
4. In the user variable section, select Path and click Edit….
5. Click New, and enter the path to the dart-sdk directory.
6. In each window that you just opened, click Apply or OK to dismiss it and apply the path change.